# Proper redirection to avoid www/non-www pages being counted as duplicates

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-redirect, slim-3

Site audits (Semrush, Seobility) point out that one of our biggest issues is duplicate content, stating that "This website uses URLs with www and non-www subdomain. This may cause duplicate content and bad links to your website."

So, basically www.oursite.com/about and oursite.com/about are counted as duplicate:

[image]

The site is built in PHP with the Slim framework. A middleware handles the use of https across the whole site. In addition, currently we have an .htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?oursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!public)(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

This code manages the routing of all pages through the public folder.

How can we edit this code in order to avoid www and non-www addresses being counted as duplicates?

Comment: If it's reporting that "This website uses URLs with www and non-www subdomain" then that sounds like it's suggesting that your site is actually linking to both www and non-www URLs internally? Is that the case?! Or is it simply stating that both are available? Which do you have a preference for? www or non-www?

Comment: I just included an image of what Semrush is showing as duplicate. For every page we have it appear there are two, one with www and one without www. Linking within the sites is handled by the Slim routing system. Our preference would be without www.

Comment: Just add a .htaccess permanent redirect from the www version to the non-www version? Note that, last time I looked into it, it's not possible to run non-www URLs behind certain proxies, like load balancers, caches, etc., in case that's something you think you might be using in the future.

Comment: Are you serving multiple domains from this account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Our preference would be without www.

Assuming you're not linking to absolute URLs in your HTML source (which would need to be updated) then you could add something like the following *before* your existing rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the requested host starts `www.` then redirect to the canonical URL.

> A middleware handles the use of https across the whole site.

Just to note that this may result in 2 redirects when requesting `http://www.example.com/` (HTTP + www). But that isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks, this eliminated the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being

Ex. I open [https://cctvinstallationpune.com](https://cctvinstallationpune.com/pune/cctv-camera-installation-services) via browser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).